# How can I keep my line of text from breaking?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to keep my line of text from breaking in two using some code that is similar to this.

```
<h3>
 <div class="home_widget">
  <div class="home_widget_lc">join us</div>
   on sundays</div>
</h3>
```

Using this code it is breaking between the "us" and "on." I want it all on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to change the "home_widget_lc" `div` into a `span`.

(Of course you can change the display property of the `div`, but if you don't have a need for a block there, don't use a block element in the first place!)

Comment: Other reason for not using a block element here: there's an h3 around it/them and that's invalid

Comment: @FelipeAls That's a good one. I'm not too concerned with what elements can contain what other elements these days, since the HTML definition is still changing, but I do remember at least in HTML 4.01 you're right.

Comment: That one didn't change in HTML5. The biggest change is `a` allowed around elements like `h3`, `p`, etc (even many headings/paragraphs)

Comment: @FelipeAls OK, OK, but still, I'm more concerned about semantics than about what can contain what. Semantics. If you need a block, use a block element; if you need a table, use a table; if you have a h2 directly following a h3 you're probably doing it wrong. Things like that are more important to me than "can a h3 contain a div" or "is element xxx currently deprecated or have they un-deprecated it again".

Comment: span and div both have no semantics so I don't get it. The first sentence of your answer is perfectly fine (thus +1) and the second part of the second one is also fine *but* not the first part as it's forbidden by HTML4.01 and 5 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Fix the markup: `h3` is not allowed to have block-level children like `div`. Use `span` instead:

```
<h3>
 <span class="home_widget">
  <span class="home_widget_lc">join us</span>
   on sundays</span>
</h3>
```

Or, unless you have some reason to wrap the content of `h3` in a container, assign the class to the `h3` element (this may imply that the CSS code needs to be simplified, too):

```
<h3 class="home_widget">
  <span class="home_widget_lc">join us</span>
   on sundays
</h3>
```

If you cannot change the markup, you need to hope that it will work reasonably despite the invalidity and to add CSS that more or less tries to turn the `div` elements to `span` elements, in the styling sense. In practice, it suffices to do that for the inner `div`:

```
.home_widget_lc { display: inline; }
```

Depending on whether the class name `home_widget_lc` is used elsewhere for other purposes, you may need to write a more specific selector to prevent the rule from having undesired effects on other elements, e.g.

```
h3 div.home_widget div.home_widget_lc { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
div {display:inline;}
```

or -

```
div.home_widget_lc {display:inline;}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Sa9W4/

You can also check this for more clarification - [**http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html**](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html)

[image]

Comment: @swapnesh You'd still have an `h3` element around `div`s and that's invalid HTML code

Comment: @FelipeAls ahh sorry for that..but can u please share a link whr i can look deeper into the subject for my own learning part :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have used  separate `div` for *join us*

```
<div class="home_widget_lc">join us</div>
```

and `div` is block element which starts from next line. The alternative of overwriting this feature of block elements you can use `display:inline` with those elements.

if you don't need special class only for *join us* you do something like this

```
<div class="home_widget_lc">join us on sundays</div>
```

Comment: There was an h3 around these div

Comment: Even if there is an h3 element, It displays `div` from next line

Comment: If there's still an h3 element, then your code is invalid. That's the next problem. (and if you remove it, then you've changed the meaning of the page)

Answer (score 0):

By default `<div>` tags are set to `display: block`.

Either change the CSS:

```css
.home_widget, .home_widget_lc {
  display: inline;
}
```

or change the HTML:

```html
<h3>
 <span class="home_widget">
  <span class="home_widget_lc">join us</span>
     on sundays
  </span>
</h3>
```

Comment: You'd still have an `h3` element around `div`s and that's invalid HTML code

Comment: The `<h3>` is fine, the blocks inside are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

can you alter the HTML?

```
<h3>
 join us on sundays
</h3>
```

All in one line.

Comment: One of the few valid answer gets downvoted without a comment. Meh

Comment: @FelipeAls I think it's downvoted because it no longer contains the classes that were in the OP's question.